# Filtrar datos de acuerdo a usuario con sesión activa en consulta SQL

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo una tabla que muestra datos de una base de datos. Los datos los estoy filtrando de la siguiente manera.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM servicios WHERE cedulaprocesado = ".$_SESSION['cedula']." ORDER By ID DESC";
```

Todo bien hasta allí. El problema que tengo es en el momento de filtrar un dato específico. Quiero filtrar la palabra que coloco a mi caja de busca, pero sólo los datos de la persona que inició sesión. Sin embargo, no me hace la consulta. Al buscar me muestra los datos de todos los usuarios y yo solo quiero que me muestre de la persona que inició sesión. Aquí les dejo la consulta `SQL` que hice pero no funciona como quiero.

```
if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
    $q = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM servicios WHERE cedulaprocesado = ".$_SESSION['cedula']." AND id LIKE '%$q%' OR nombreapellido LIKE '%$q%' OR cedula LIKE '%$q%'";
}
```

Comment: Estas encerrando una consulta dentro de otra consulta? o que contiene la variable POST en su pocision consulta?

Comment: si entendi bien el problema es el where, intenta poniendolo asi: `WHERE cedulaprocesado = ".$_SESSION['cedula']." AND (id LIKE '%$q%' OR nombreapellido LIKE '%$q%' OR cedula LIKE '%$q%')";`. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Falta informacion para darte una respuesta completa, sin embargo puede que el error este directamente al final de tu consulta

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM servicios WHERE cedulaprocesado = ".$_SESSION['cedula']." AND id LIKE '%$q%' OR nombreapellido LIKE '%$q%' OR cedula LIKE '%$q%'";
```

Para ser especificos en las ultimas dos condicionales de tu `WHERE`

```
AND id LIKE '%$q%' OR nombreapellido LIKE '%$q%' OR cedula LIKE '%$q%'
```

Estas diciendole a tu tabla que te traiga todos los datos que tengan una cedula profesiona, ademas de eso debe ser parecido al `id` tanto al princpio como al final o que un nombre y apelllido sean parecidos a lo que estas ingresando o que una cedula sea igual a otra cedula, ademas de que en todo momento estas instanciando a la misma varible, es por ello tu error.

En pocas palabras tu error es logico, tu consulta estructuralmente y semanticamente esta bien, pero logicamente no.

Ahora, para darte una respuesta mas clara y una posible solucion necesitaria entender tu variable `$q` te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta añadiendo estos detalles para que yo o alguien de la comunidad te pueda dar una mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

te faltan unos paréntesis entre después del `AND`.

Algo así:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM servicios WHERE cedulaprocesado = ".$_SESSION['cedula']." AND (id LIKE '%$q%' OR nombreapellido LIKE '%$q%' OR cedula LIKE '%$q%')";
```

Comment: muchas gracias solo eso eras me salvaste